# In maven - how to display a message to the user when the verify phase is run on the default execution?

Tags: java, maven, warnings, maven-surefire-plugin

In our maven build - we're using the default profile for builds, and a different profile for tests. When our tests are run under the default profile, for various reasons they break.

eg good in our team with our build

```
mvn -Pfoo verify
```

bad in our team with our build

```
mvn verify
```

We want to encourage people in our team to run the tests under the 'foo' lifecycle, and warn them when they don't.

My current approach to solving this problem is to create a new surefire test for the default profile, exclude all the tests except a new `DefaultProfileWarningTest` whose sole purpose is to tell the user to run the tests under the `foo` profile.

So the test might look like:

```
public class DefaultProfileWarningTest {
    @Test
    public void displayWarning() {
        System.out.println("The tests aren't running - you should have run **mvn -Pfoo verify**");
    }
}
```

With an execution in the `pom.xml` similar to:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>foo</id>
        ...      
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>my-default-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>DefaultProfileWarningTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

But this seems like an overwrought kludge. Assuming we can't fix the profile thing - is there a simple lightweight way to display a message to the user when the verify phase is for the default profile?

My question is: **In maven - how to display a message to the user when the verify phase is run on the default execution?**

Comment: Why do you need a message? Furthermore what do you use the maven-surefire-plugin by using a profile...if those tests are integration tests than you should better use maven-failsafe-plugin which means they only will run if you do `mvn clean verfiy` if you do`mvn clean package` they won't run...if your team member want to do a `mvn deploy` the integration tests will run...

Comment: Apart from that if those tests are breaking than you should fix those test to get them running otherwise running those tests does not make sense...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise - that was a good prompt - I've re investigated that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to define an execution of the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) that echos a message with the [`echo`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) task. It would be skipped when run under the `foo` profile, using the attribute [`skip`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#skip). The switch can be made from a Maven property that is set to `true` in the `foo` profile and `false` by default.

Consider the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo>The tests aren't running - you should have run mvn -Pfoo verify</echo>
                </target>
                <skip>${isRightProfile}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you can configure your profiles like so:

```
<profile>
    <id>foo</id>
    <properties>
        <isRightProfile>true</isRightProfile>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>my-default-profile</id>
    <properties>
        <isRightProfile>false</isRightProfile>
    </properties>
    <!-- rest unchanged -->
</profile>
```

When the `foo` profile is activated, the `isRightProfile` property will be set to `true`, so the execution of the AntRun plugin will be skipped and no messages will be printed. When the default profile is activated, this property will be set to `false` and the messages will be echoed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an appropriate plugin like the [echo-maven-plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/Maven-Echo-Plugin/)  to print out a message.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>echo</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <echos>
      <echo>This is the Text which will be printed out.</echo>
    </echos>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you like to force people to use a particular profile you should use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireActiveProfile.html) which can force you to use a particular profile.